# Import XML Workspace Document Fails ArcGis pro

Tags: xml, arcmap, fme

I am trying to importing the XML Document (schema only ) into the working File Geodatabase.
I export xml document from ArcCatalog /Arcmap ,ArcGis enterprise 10.8.1
I have used import geodatabase ArcGis pro but I got error and I have also tried to use FME
To write into file geodatabase by using xml document schema but I got this error
The error number from ArcObjects is: '-2147220735'. The error message from ArcObjects is: {Unable to create object class extension COM component
Name.Feature class name
Could someone provide me some advices ?what should I do ?
My target to import xml document to file geodatabase
Thanks in advance

I have used import xml to geodatabase and I have used FME but without success

Comment: Converting the error number to hex I found following : https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-network-analyst-questions/problem-of-using-tutorial-to-create-a-network/td-p/1078154/page/2

Comment: @jdweng it has no relation with my problem but thanks for the link .

Comment: Are you running with ArcGIS Pro 2.9 or newer.  According to link there was a bug that was fixed.

Comment: Latest version is 11.1.  Here is a list of bugs that were fixed : https://links.esri.com/issues_fixed111

Comment: I am running with ArcGis pro 3.1 but I did not see any error for importing xml to geodatabase that you provided . Do u have an idea ,how to fix unable to create object class extension com component error ?what does it mean

Comment: This may be a window issue.  See : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-error-code-80040301-in-file-history/fbade0af-2fac-493d-8a05-9f549fdcbf58  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism?view=windows-11

Comment: @jdweng please do not reply again .u bring always stuff has no relation with the topic .

Comment: Is the issue your code or is the issue the library updates?